# Clicking inside the bounds of a button text triggers the button

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts, mesh

I just imported a [font](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/fonts/pixel-font-tripfive-64734) from the asset store. To use it with the UI the author says i should use the Scale property of the Rect Transform to change the size of the font, setting the font size does not work for this asset.

So i create a button, attatch the font to the text component of the child gameobject and scale it up to a proper size.

When testing the app i notice that button triggers when i click outside of its bounds. I check again and confirm that the button triggers when i click inside the bounds of gamobject that holds the text component.

How do i tell unity to use the bounds of the button itself, not the ones of its child gameobject?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the handles and bounds of your text object?

[image: Raycast target]

All of that still counts.

The easiest way to fix this is to uncheck `RaycastTarget` (in yellow), however you may wish to investigate why the text object is so large instead. I see a scale of `(3,3,3)` in the transform, which is not standard. You should reset this to `(1,1,1)` and increase the font size instead. Also check the parent object's scale, boundaries, and anchors.

Additionally, your other two buttons are probably similarly affected.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the actual graphic you're seeing (Add Ammo) is just the text and it's background. You may have just resized that without realizing it's parent object, the actual thing in the game environment called "Add Ammo Button", actually took up half the screen. Hence why clicking on the bottom part of the screen triggers it.

The collision box does not seem to be limited to only the visible graphics.